# Rename multiple directories in the command line

Tags: directory, rename, batch

I have some folders called:

```
Session 1
Session 2
Session 3
Session 4
Session 5
Session 6
Session 7
Session 8
```

I would like to rename them all to:

```
Folder 1
Folder 2
Folder 3
Folder 4
Folder 5
Folder 6
Folder 7
Folder 8
```

How would I go about doing this in the terminal in the most effective way?

I know about `mmv` `mv` and `rename` but not sure what I should use and how to do it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### prename

Simplest way would be to use `rename` or `prename`, which is a Perl script ( if you're a `ksh` or `mksh` user, that shell has `rename` built-in function, which is different, so for the sake of consistency, I'll use `prename` when referring to that Perl script; alternatively you could call `/usr/bin/rename` - full path to the executable).

```
$ ls
Session 1/  Session 2/  Session 3/  Session 4/  Session 5/  Session 6/  Session 7/  Session 8/
$ prename 's/Session/Folder/' Session*/                                                                                  
$ ls
Folder 1/  Folder 2/  Folder 3/  Folder 4/  Folder 5/  Folder 6/  Folder 7/  Folder 8/
```

If you need recursive search or ensure that you find the right type of item ( maybe you also have files with word "Session" in the filename) you can combine that with `find` utility:

```
$ ls
Folder 1/  Folder 2/  Folder 3/  Folder 4/  Folder 5/  Folder 6/  Folder 7/  Folder 8/

$ find -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "Session *" -exec prename 's/Session/Folder/' {} \;                                      

$ ls
Folder 1/  Folder 2/  Folder 3/  Folder 4/  Folder 5/  Folder 6/  Folder 7/  Folder 8/
```

Slightly lengthy, maybe slightly redundant, but works.

#### mv

The small problem with `mv` is that we need to alter the name of the destination each time, so by itself it can't do what we want. To do that, we'd have to combine it with some other tools, such as `find` or `bash`'s tools.

```
$ ls
Session 1/  Session 2/  Session 3/  Session 4/  Session 5/  Session 6/  Session 7/  Session 8/


$ for dir in Session*/ ; do mv "${dir}" "Folder ${dir##*\ }" ;done                                                       

$ ls
Folder 1/  Folder 2/  Folder 3/  Folder 4/  Folder 5/  Folder 6/  Folder 7/  Folder 8/
```

What you see here is that we're looping over all items that contain the word `Session` in them and are directory. We use parameter expansion `${dir##*\ }" to extract everything after space in directory's name ( which is the respective number), and form new string "Folder /".

In both `prename` commands and `mv` we're using globbing, which means these approaches will rename *every* directory that contains the word "Session" in them, even "Session blah". Not ideal, of course, but for the specific case where you know your folder naming is consistent, that'll work. Alternatively, we could augment the command with `for dir in Session\ [1-9] ; do . . .done`.

In other words,this approach can work, but is very simplistic and isn't the best.

#### Python

Of course, other tools can be used as well. For instance, Python:

```
$ ls
Session 1/  Session 3/  Session 5/  Session 7/
Session 2/  Session 4/  Session 6/  Session 8/

$ python -c 'import os,shutil;map(lambda x:shutil.move(x,x.replace("Session","Folder")),os.listdir("."))'                

$ ls
Folder 1/  Folder 2/  Folder 3/  Folder 4/  Folder 5/  Folder 6/  Folder 7/  Folder 8/
```

Comment: Great, I used the first solution and it does exactly what I wanted. Is there any difference between using `prename` and `rename`?

Comment: Nevermind, I see the update.

Comment: @Danchm01 I was in the process of editing my answer, when you posted the comment, and the edit addresses exactly that. Basically, I'd prefer `prename`  because if you're using Korn shell or its derivative instead of `bash` , there is a shell built in command named `rename` , so the syntax for `prename` wont work there and you'll have to explicitly call `/usr/bin/rename` to make it work.

Comment: If you cannot use python2, then this works `python3 -c 'import os,shutil;list(map(lambda x:shutil.move(x,x.replace("Session","Folder")),os.listdir(".")))'    `

Answer (score 2):

Go to the folder that contens all the folder you want to rename and do:

```
find . * | rename 's\Session\Folder\'
```

Comment: rename's syntax is with slash, not back slash. This piping will not work. one needs find . *  -exec rename 's/Session/Folder/' {} \;